# Import AWS IAM role into terraform state using apex.run

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, apex

I am managing my AWS infrastructure with terraform and apex. I need help to import one IAM Role resource which was previously created, so that to add it into the terraform state.
I have already added the resource into my terraform .tf file.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "default_role" {
  name = "default_role_name"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Based on terraform documentation on how to import an IAM Role ([aws_iam_role](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html)) I need to do something like:

`$ terraform import aws_iam_role.default_role default_role_name`

and I am not doing this using the default `profile` and `env`, so in apex I am trying

`$ apex infra -e myEnv -p myProfile init`

`$ apex infra -e myEnv -p myProfile import aws_iam_role.default_role default_role_name`

The init call is successful, but the import call is unsuccessful (also changed the order of parameters), as I get a list of possible commands (as if you run the command with `--help`), but either with `Error: exit status 1` or `Error: exit status 127`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error output?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR http://prntscr.com/p0l92s
http://prntscr.com/p0la94
http://prntscr.com/p0lapz
I couldnt edit my post, it gave me some code formatting error.

Comment: What makes you think that you can run an import like this? Looking at https://github.com/apex/apex/blob/9a7686bae601935091db4bb403e69c6e7cc1c599/cmd/apex/main.go#L44-L59 it doesn't look like this is an allowed thing.

Comment: Thought import is also supported, and when I do `apex infra --help` import is available (which is the actual terraform help)
Think I need to use terraform itself for this purpose.